# How to change the position of the color picker

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is a simple example, but what I would like to do is change the position of the color picker to the same area of the button.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('test').click();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
  Test
  </h1>
  <div>
    <div style="float:right">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </div>
    <div hidden="true">
      <input type="color" id="test">
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can set the position for the native input

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this with Javascript:

```
var buttonElement = document.getElementById('yourButtonId');
var divElement = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
divElement.style.position = "absolute";
divElement.style.left = buttonElement.style.left+'px';
divElement.style.top = buttonElement.style.top+'px';
```

I'd put that code in a function called something like `moveColorPicker()` and then call that in `myFunction()`